# Result set data upload to azure storage location as Text/CSV file

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage

How can we export the result set of a specific select query into a file (CSV/TEXT) in Azure storage location ?? Is there any possibility to implement using SQL or is there any already implemented maintenance mechanism for the same, like a maintenance plan ?? I need something like the code must be able to create a file having the result set of a specific select query executed and which must be uploaded to the given azure storage location.

I'm looking for the following scenario. **I want to delete some data from an overloaded table and export those data into a CSV or TXT file which needs to be uploaded into the azure blob storage location in which this task should get executed at regular intervals**. I must be able to configure for multiple databases within the same instance as well for multiple tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure Data factory and its [Copy Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/v1/data-factory-data-movement-activities) to export the result of a query as a CSV file located on Azure Storage.

The copy activity may look similar to the following:

```
{  
    "name":"SamplePipeline",
    "properties":{  
    "start":"2014-06-01T18:00:00",
    "end":"2014-06-01T19:00:00",
    "description":"pipeline for copy activity",
    "activities":[  
      {
        "name": "AzureSQLtoBlob",
        "description": "copy activity",
        "type": "Copy",
        "inputs": [
          {
            "name": "AzureSQLInput"
          }
        ],
        "outputs": [
          {
            "name": "AzureBlobOutput"
          }
        ],
        "typeProperties": {
          "source": {
            "type": "SqlSource",
            "SqlReaderQuery": "$$Text.Format('select * from MyTable where timestampcolumn >= \\'{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm}\\' AND timestampcolumn < \\'{1:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm}\\'', WindowStart, WindowEnd)"
          },
          "sink": {
            "type": "BlobSink"
          }
        },
       "scheduler": {
          "frequency": "Hour",
          "interval": 1
        },
        "policy": {
          "concurrency": 1,
          "executionPriorityOrder": "OldestFirst",
          "retry": 0,
          "timeout": "01:00:00"
        }
      }
     ]
   }
}
```

You will find more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/v1/data-factory-azure-sql-connector).

Comment: thanks for your reply. I'm looking for such a way that the result set must be exported as a text or csv file directly from sql (using some plsql) which should be created in the specified azure blob storage location. For example  **sqlcmd -U daniel -S sqlshack.cloudapp.net -P “yourpassword” -d master -i “c:\scripts\test.sql” -o “<AzureStorageLocation>\results.txt”**  we should be able to pass the azure storage location.

Comment: @Jesalcv you will have to write some code, there is no built-in functionality

Comment: @Jesalcv  try this ..... bcp AutoAssoc.dbo.VehicleSalesCurrent in C:\JohnDonnelly\VehicleSalesCurrent.csv -f C:\JohnDonnelly\VehicleSalesCurrent.xml -U johndonnelly@xxxxxxxxxx -S tcp:xxxxxxxx.database.windows.net -P XXXXXXXX

Comment: @AlbertoMorillo, Thanks for the leads. Since i have specifically defined individual blob containers for each databases, i need to specify the blob location (say abc-xyz is my container name) for each file. How can i accommodate the same into the code ??

Comment: Is it possible in your scenario to create the file locally using bcp and then move it using AZCopy?